# jquery select and update head node in ajax $.get call

Tags: jquery

I want to achieve the really easy task to replace the head node of a page with the head node of the page called with an ajax call.

I do it like this:

```
        url = 'http://myurl';                    
        $.get(url, function(results){
          var head = $('head', results);

          $('head', results).each (
             function() {
                 alert("got a match ");
             });


          var form = $("form.ajax_form_result", results);
          //update the ajax_form_result div with the return value "form"
          $('head').html(head);
          $('#ajax_form_result').html(form);
        }, "html");
```

The form updates work without problems, but the head update does not work. $("head", results); does not return a node, resulting in an empty head in the new document.

Comment: Hey Tom Tom,
Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to dot he same thing right now and having the same problem.

Comment: No, I finally came to the conclusion that there has to be another solution then replacing the head node, and restructured my issue and was not anymore obliged to reload the head node. Still I would be curious why the head is always empty.

Answer (score 1):

try:   `$("head", $(results));`

"results" should just be a block of text in html format.
"$(result)" should be that block transformed in DOM objects.

Comment: I tried it but it does not change anything. Both approaches lead to the same result, an empty head ;-) Whereas I'm sure that my ajax call returns a complete html page with a head tag.

Answer (score 0):

This worked well for me:

```
var feed = http://www.feed.com/page.html;

jQuery.get('http://yourdomain.com/proxy.php?url='+feed+'', function(html){
    if (html == '') {
        alert('Invalid URL');
        return false;
    } 

    html = html.replace( /<(\/?)(html|head|body)([^>]*)>/ig, function(a,b,c,d){
        return '<' + b + 'div' + ( b ? '' : ' data-element="' + c + '"' ) + d + '>';
    });

    RSSlink = jQuery(html).find('[data-element=head]').find('link[type="application/rss+xml"]').eq(0).attr('href');

});
```

It should be able to do what you need it to do!

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented this solution to my problem:

```
var myUrl="http://urlExampleSubstituteWithYour"
$.get( url, function( data ) {
    // Get the string index of the content of the start head tag
    var startHead=(data.toString().indexOf("<head>"))+6;
    // Get the string index of the finish head tag
    var stopHead=data.toString().indexOf("</head>");
    // Create a string of the head content of the myUrl page
    var head=data.substring(startHead+6,stopHead);
    // Apply HTML to my block...
    $("#idOfMyBlock").html(head);
});
```

This solution (maybe not the best) has saved me!
Sorry for my english!